# Persist complex object with @RepositoryRestController and Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.7, Spring Data REST, Hibernate, Spring Validation, Hateoas.

I'm working on a Angular client consuming my REST API. Because I'm using HATEOAS when I need to send an existant object instead to send the id, i send the uri of the resource.

With this bean:

```
@Entity
public class Movement extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    @Min(value = 0)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant currencyDate = Instant.now();
```

and the payment type:

```
@Entity
public class PaymentType extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1771796458999002051L;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]+", message = "{Pattern.paymenttype.code}")
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "UPPER(code)", write = "UPPER(?)")
    private String code;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

I want to persist a Movement addind it to another entity that references it. So I created this endpoint:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/ticketBundles")
public class TicketBundleController {

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/{id}/payments")   
    public ResponseEntity<?> addPayment(@PathVariable(value = "id") long ticketBundleId,
            @RequestBody(required = true) Movement payment) {
            //my implementation
    }
```

From the client I call the endpoint sending this json that is the json representation of the Movement object:

```
{
"currencyDate":"2017-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
"amount":150,
"paymentType": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2"
}
```

But I've an exception on the server:

```
12/10/2017 23:07:38,526  WARN http-nio-8080-exec-4 ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:391 -
            Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of server.model.accounting.PaymentType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of server.model.accounting.PaymentType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5c7f71af; line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: server.model.accounting.MovementTicketBundle["paymentType"])
    at server.config.exceptions.ApplicationExceptionHandler.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(ApplicationExceptionHandler.java:31) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java:164) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:380) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at server.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:64) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of server.model.accounting.PaymentType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of server.model.accounting.PaymentType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5c7f71af; line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: server.model.accounting.MovementTicketBundle["paymentType"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 98 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of server.model.accounting.PaymentType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5c7f71af; line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: server.model.accounting.MovementTicketBundle["paymentType"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:370) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:315) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1282) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:150) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:104) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:357) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2938) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 98 more
12/10/2017 23:07:38,528  WARN http-nio-8080-exec-4 DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:384 -
            Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of server.model.accounting.PaymentType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of server.model.accounting.PaymentType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5c7f71af; line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: server.model.accounting.MovementTicketBundle["paymentType"])
```

Seems Spring Data REST is not able to translate the URI to the corresponding resource.
Am I doing something wrong, is that a desired behaviour or is that a bug? Some advice to fix the problem?

Comment: how spring supposed to map `"paymentType": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paymentTypes/2"` string to `PaymentType` object? i mean you have to setup jackson deserializer or some sort of jackson annotations or maybe custom constructor with single string argument to help json parser

Comment: @varren I didn't set up any deserializer. The fact is SDR is able to do that in MovementRepository without the need of any deserializer. And because the annotation RepositoryRestController I'm using in my controller says that you benefit of " request handling, message converters, exception handling, etc. ", I expected the conversion worked as in standard CRUD repository.

Comment: `MovementRepository` is probably using serializer and not deserializer, but i cant be 100% sure. anyway. the error you provided shows exactly that jackson is looking for `"paymentType": {"code":"somecode","name":"somename"}` and cant figure out how to parse single string

Comment: @varren MovementRepository provides also deserializer because I use that also to POST (persist) a Movement with also paymentType. Anyway, are you able to provide a working example to deserialize my uri considering I've this problem for a lot of other beans? So how could SDR understand just from the argument type? I guess I should parse the URI and check the path to understand to wich entity it belongs. A working example would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In this case you have created a custom controller so you probably need to deal with some of these conversions yourself. Can you avoid the custom controller? Use the SDR endpoint rather than a custom controller and do your additional processing in an Event listener: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Comment: @AlanHay could you provide an example of conversion classes needed? I would like to avoid the use of the custom controller. I like your idea. Unfortunately, because my parent entity has a List<Movement> seems the endpoint SDR creates to do the POST doesn't work so well. It gives an error like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: {"content": org.springframework.hateoas.UriTemplate.expand(UriTemplate.java:194). Seems SDR is trying to resolve an URI but I'm not passing an URI. an example of this would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Problems with links** RestController needs to use HAL MessageConverter so you have to hint him

1. With `org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<Movement>`

   ```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/{id}/payments")   
   public ResponseEntity<?> addPayment(
            @RequestBody(required = true) Resourse<Movement> m) {
           //implementation
   }
   ```
2. or maybe `application/hal+json` media type  would be also needed

---

**Problems with date/time** conversion like `Instant`.  You probably already have [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310) module but if you don't it can help https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer objectMapperBuilder() {
    return builder -> {
        builder.modules(new JavaTimeModule());
    };
}
```

---

Other problem can be that you use hal unrelated jackson Object mapper in your custom rest controller. Take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/333#issuecomment-93490403) or [here](https://gist.github.com/ripla/6f1516e3d0c28f4d591303d4060342d4#file-restconfiguration-java-L20-L30) So you need to make some setup.

But i think even that can fail according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.custom-jackson-deserialization)

> Sometimes the behavior of the Spring Data REST’s ObjectMapper, which
>   has been specially configured to use intelligent serializers that can
>   turn domain objects into links and back again, may not handle your
>   domain model correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Trying your first suggestion I get an empty Resource.

Comment: @drenda here is demo code that works for me https://github.com/varren/SpringRepositoryRestControllerDemo Probably you can look into it and tell what you do differently. You can run tests there and they will show that controller works just fine in my case. I also added some `PaymentType` records in db for demo purpose.

Comment: thank you for the git project. I just tried it. The test case works but if you inspect the Movement bean you will see inside it's empty. Be amount is 0, the date is now() and not what you sent, the payment type is null.

Comment: @drenda hm, that's strange.  works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA5zG.png  log message of `Got request and payment is:` is log in controller and then i return from controller same object as a json without hal links and print it in test. Really strange, that you get something different.

Comment: That is very strange. I got the code from github. I run that on a Mac but I don't see what should be wrong with that.

Comment: @drenda my setup is `OpenJDK build 8u131 Ubuntu 16.04` also works just fine on `Oracle JDK build 8u144 Windows 10 `